# Different behaviour of R program in Ubuntu AWS and Ubuntu laptop

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, server

```
library(statcomp)
library(igraph)
library(NetworkDistance)
library(png)
a   <- readPNG("001.png")
  c   <- list(a, col=1, byrow= TRUE)
  d   <- unlist(c)
  d   <- d[1:1024]
  e   <- ts(d)
  hr1 <- HVG(e, meth = "HVG", maxL = 10^9, rho = NA)
  hr1 <- hr1$A
    l <- readPNG("002.png")
    n <- list(l, col=1, byrow= TRUE)
    p <- unlist(n)
    p <- p[1:1024]
    q <- ts(p)
    hr2 <- HVG(q, meth = "HVG", maxL = 10^9, rho = NA)
    hr3 <- hr2$A
    x <- list(hr1,hr3 )
    y <-nd.him(x, out.dist = TRUE)
```

This  program is executing properly in laptop but  in Amaon server  it is giving error

```
Error in if ((as.double(RSpectra::eigs(matD, 1, which = "SM")$values)) <  : 
  argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In do.call(.Call, args = dot_call_args) :
  only 0 eigenvalue(s) converged, less than k = 1
```

do you  have any idea how i can solve this problem?

Comment: Different versions?

Comment: both of them have lastest r